# Generate a list of of subfolders only in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I've been trying to write a line of code that auto generates a list of subfolders in one specific folder.

With the code below I've managed to get a list of files but I haven't been able to adapt the code to get subfolders only.

Could someone please help me out?

Cheers
Andy

How I got the files

```
function listFilesInFolder(id) {
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID]');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Mockups');
  var date;
  var size;
  var link;

  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Annons", "Länk", "Uppladdad"]);


  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    date = file.getDateCreated()
    size = file.getSize()
    link = file.getUrl();

    data = [name, link, date, ]
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
};
```

Comment: To the Drive API, folders are just files with a specific `mimeType`. Review the Drive Service / Drive API documentation. (When using the Drive Service, it has methods explicitly geared towards interacting with `Folder`s.)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there are folder specific commands. Modify your function with something like this:

```
var subFolders = folder.getFolders();

while (subFolders.hasNext()
  {    
  var childFolder = childFolders.next(); 

  var folderID = childFolder.getId();    
  Logger.log(folderID);    
  }
```

Comment: ah thanks thats what i've been looking for! I'll let you know how it works

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with the code below.

Thanks J. G. for the help, your input made it work!

```
function generateFolderIndex(id) {
   var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('[ID]');
   var subFolders = folder.getFolders();
   var childFolders = subFolders
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Projekt');

   sheet.clear();
   sheet.appendRow(["Projekt", "Länk", "Skapad"]);

while (subFolders.hasNext())
  {    
  var childFolder = childFolders.next(); 

  var folderID = childFolder.getId();
  var name = childFolder.getName()
  var link = childFolder.getUrl()
  var date = childFolder.getDateCreated()


   data = [name, link, date, ]
    sheet.appendRow(data);

  }
};
```